# How to update attribute value while iterating Flux

Tags: java, reactive, flux

I want to update an attribute value for each item in list with the value present in another list.I am trying to do it via Map but it is giving me compile error. Can somebody please suggest what is the correct way to do this ? I am new to reactive.

```
private void updatePaymentDocument(Payment paymentDoc, PaymentTransaction txn) {
    Flux.fromIterable(paymentDoc.getPaymentMethods())
    .filter( pm-> pm.getSequenceNo().equalsIgnoreCase(txn.getSequenceNo()))
    .map(pm -> pm.setTotalRefundAmount(txn.getPaymentAuthorization().getAuthorizedAmount()));
}
```

Comment: if you are doing something get or  set like a consumer ,  not supplier , you can try with  doonnext instead of map , map is used to  trans the model from upstream to downstream

Comment: `map` takes a `Function` that needs to return a value. `setTotalRefundAmount` most likely has a `void` return type. Besides using `doOnNext` you can try using a block: `{ pm.setTotalRefundAmount(...); return pm; }`